# How to store and serve 4 billions images?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, cloud

I would like to build my own web page thumb-shots cloud service for my private usage.
I plan to have more that 4,000,000,000 small images (10KB)
I do not want to use an external service like amazon S3, I want to build my own cloud.

How will you store that and keep it scalable ?
For exemple, onto a cassandra distributed database, or a GlusterFS filesystem ...

How will you serve that efficiently through HTTP ?
For exemple, use a nginx load balancer to many http servers reading the cassandra database...

Answer (score 2):

You question is vague and ill researched and formed however I will place some pointers here.

> thumb-shots cloud service for my private usage.

If this is for your own personal usage I would strongly recommend NOT using a database at all, but instead a file system on a High IOPs SSD backed cluster (set of servers) specifically tuned to high network utilisation and IO reads.

Note: This will quickly expand to be way more expensive than an external service like S3.

> How will you securely store that (it requires 40TB) ?

This is a little broad and lacks any real research by the sounds of it but you could secure it from the web app end and put rules into the image servers firewalls stating that only the web app is allowed access to the images. Then in your web app you would have rules to secure your image usage.

> How will you serve that efficiently through HTTP ?

Through caching mechanisms, both on the server (in the web app) in the form of Varnish or something and also within the browser by adding a infinite expire time (possibly).

Of course, the "best" caching mechanism depends on the web server and usage, i.e. Nginx or Apache.

This is a base answer for a vague and overly broad question. I would strongly recommend you do some research and look into image serving through whatever server you wish to use.

Comment: External service like S3 seems to me very expensive : if I take a bunch of servers from my provider, I put a distributed filesystem on them, it is already 4x cheaper than S3. If I add the cost of IOs and bandwidth, amazon S3 is 10x more expensive... this is why I would like to make my own cloud.

Comment: @Eric To make that distribution work with an real speed you will soon find it costs a lot of money, I suppose if you wanted to cut corners and not make it that fast then yea, it would be cheaper

Comment: It is interesting : what are the costs you are speaking about to have a fast service ?

Comment: @Eric Oooh that's a complicated matter, for the high IOP SSDs alone you could be going into the thousands a month for 40TB, and then for the distribution network and the bandwidth, well yeah....a lot

Comment: That's the point : my provider give me a very very cheap but still high quality bandwith. In addition, I have a internal 10Gbps vlan for almost free. About ssd, I prefer split IOs and storage on sevral servers with standard disks. I only need a good glue : GlusterFS, Cassandra ... that the reason of my question.

Comment: There once was a library called epeg, that was part of Enlightenment, which was billed as 'lightning fast jpeg thumbnailing'.  it was easy to wrap in python , perl , or make your own binaries with.  i haven't used it in years, but in 2005 it was several orders of magnitude faster than just about every other alternative out there.  IIRC, it did some fancy stuff to sample images and then encode those samples with libjpeg, so you didn't have to read the entire image.

Comment: @Eric Hmm I suppose if the ISP serves everything you need then maybe that is best and about the glue, for the images themselves I would not use any database, you will get better performance from the file system imo, make sure to not put too many files in the same directory due to slow IO reads though. As for the web app, the database depends on the web app itself, if it is solely to serve images then MySQL or something easy and simple to learn could easily suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the biggest issue is to find a storage of such capacity, but even if you'll find, I don't think that any usual database can handle such amount of data, so you will need to write some custom solution for storing/reading.
Anyway, if you could describe your original problem, there might be some other real solution without a need of storing such amount of images, because working with 4 billion images is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use blobs (Binary Large OBjectS). Did you consider Google App Engine's blobstore? If you're not familiar with BLOBs then it's a good and cheap way to get started with cloud computing and image serving. You can program you blobhandling in python, java or google's new compiled language go. If you use GAE you will also be able to do everything with applications and you won't have to worry about harddrives or operating systems. If you want to make an own stack you should look which kind of clustering your service provider supports.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this may be of interest:
http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/

It's just been open-sourced, and is explicitly designed for building your own S3

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack Swift is an object storage project that is used by Rackspace as well as Wikimedia to store millions of images.

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/